# How to sort albums the same as Photos.app

Tags: ios, photokit

I want to sort albums the same way as Photos.app. I tried every possible `PHFetchOptions` for `PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with type: subtype:options:)`:

- nil
- default without specifying `sortDescriptors`
- sortDescriptors with `localizedTitle`, `title`, `startDate`, `endDate,`estimatedAssetCount`

But none gives the same order as Photos.app.

Comment: @Bill No. One is sorting albums, one is sorting photos.

Comment: You're right. I retracted my close vote. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
// get Photos timeline
guard let timelineFetchResult = PHCollectionList.fetchMomentLists(with: .momentListCluster, options: nil).firstObject else { return }

// get Moments seperated by photos' creation date
let momentsFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchMoments(inMomentList: timelineFetchResult, options: nil)

// get photos from every Moment
for index in 0 ..< momentsFetchResult.count {
    let moment = momentsFetchResult[index]
    let assetsFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: moment, options: nil)
    // ...
}
```